black rendered imagine
i have a problem with rendered imagine - its all black, and i cant fix it, i checked everything what i knew could be wrong, and i tried find help in youtube tutorials, but its still the same... i tried to make render in cycles - i usually do - i made maybe 10 renders, and suddenly i have black renders, i didnt change anything, in eevee is the same problem could anybody help me? i have to finish my project as soon as possible

I'm afraid you haven't given us enough details to even guess at what's causing your problem. Please at least provide a screenshot of your Blender window (the 3D View one, not the render output). See: How to upload an image to a post. You can also use the top Search bar here to search for posts with similar problems to yours. - There are lots of them!
